# Drools workbench push with GIT

Tags: git, drools

I have a problem, when i push a modification to drools workbench, i have this problem : 
 git://localhost/test: push not permitted

I can import project from drools but the push doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Push using the git url is not supported you have to try using SSH url .setRemote("ssh://<>@localhost:8001/<>")